# Why this equation holds, using Bayes formula?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, bayes-theorem

My **mysterious** equation is:

$$p(x|\chi)=\int_{\theta\in\Theta}p(x|\theta)p(\theta|\chi)d\theta$$

where $\chi$ is some samples drawn from sample space parameterized by $\theta\in\Theta$. Follows the bayesian tradition, we are going to estimate the newly seen sample $x$ given the old samples $\chi$.

In my opinion, I think the equation should be written as:

$$p(x|\chi)=\int_{\theta\in\Theta}p(x|\theta,\chi)p(\theta|\chi)d\theta$$

Cause this obeys the calculation of conditioning:

$$p(x,\theta|\chi)=p(x|\theta,\chi)p(\theta|\chi)$$

and then, the marginalization of $\theta$ leads to $p(x|\chi)$.

One explanation that I found hitting the point is all the samples drawn from a generative process parameterized by $\theta$ are seen as i.i.d. So the conditioning on \chi (the previous samples) could simply be removed since $x\bot\chi|\Theta$. This shows:$$p(x|\theta,\chi)=p(x|\theta)$$ Independence means: $p(x|\theta,\chi)=\frac{p(x,\chi|\theta)}{p(\chi|\theta)}=\frac{p(x|\theta)p(\chi|\theta)}{p(\chi|\theta)}=p(x|\theta)$.

I am not sure whether my derivation and argument are reasonable. Or could you tell me more about this kind of statistical inference? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes your arguments looks good. Conditional independence is a key assumption, often overlooked / not stated clearly enough.